# Tabs are not visible on a lollipop

Tags: android

I have created a fragment TabHost inside a fragment which is in an activity containing navigation drawer. The tabs are visible on KitKat and jelly beans devices but not on lollipop devices.

Fragment:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics;
    private int height;
    int textsize;

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    //private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        /*Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);*/
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_primary_option, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this,rootView);
        metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        switch(metrics.densityDpi)
        {
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                height=30;
                textsize=10;
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                height=70;
                textsize=40;
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                height=100;
                textsize=60;
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                height=100;
                textsize=60;

        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight=1;


        Log.e("TAG","before tabhost");
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        // Create the tabs in main_fragment.xml
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        // Create Tab1 with a custom image in res folder
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Jobs"),
                JobsFragment.class, null);



        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tournaments"),
                TournamentFragment .class, null);


        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Events"),
                EventsFragment.class, null);

        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");

        Log.e("TAG","after tabhost");


        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(params);
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_example);
            final TextView tab_text = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tab_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#646464"));
            tab_text.setTypeface(typeface);
            tab_text.setAllCaps(false);
            tab_text.setTextSize(16f);
            tab_text.setPadding(0,15,0,20);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        /*((Primary_Option) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));*/
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="darkhorsesports.getsporty.Primary_Option$PlaceholderFragment"
>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the tabs are displaying in lollipop emulators but not on lollipop phones.

Comment: can you post any piece of your code or the layout?

Comment: you can check the code now. This fragment contains the fragment tabhost.